# How to create custom table with different cells?

Tags: css, html, html-table, css-tables

It should be like

[image]

It should be 4 rows and 3 colums. In first column centrall cell takes 2 cells. In second it should be 1 row. And third the same as first

I have this code

```html
 <table border="1" width="100%">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td rowspan="4">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td rowspawn="2">4</td>
    <td rowspawn="2">5</td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

But it looks like this
[image]

Comment: `table {
  border-color:black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
  padding:3px;
}`

Comment: @David i am not about how it looks

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are after however, does this give you what you want?

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="4">2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:200px;" rowspawn="2">4</td>
        <td rowspawn="2">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table height="200px" width="900px" border="1px solid black">

<tr>

<td></td>
<td rowspan="4"></td>
<td></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td rowspan="2"></td>
<td rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>

</tr>

<tr>

<td></td>
<td></td>

</tr>

</table>
```

Try this code. It Works.